# How to parse .stl file in Java with best performance?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, stl-format

I got the following .stl file, that I'd like to parse and extract the coordinates:

```
solid WEMtoSTL_0
facet normal 0.999309 0.0262812 0.0262796
outer loop
vertex -49.9111 85.733 -1357.76
vertex -49.9346 86.6265 -1357.76
vertex -49.9346 85.733 -1356.86
endloop
endfacet
facet normal 0.999158 0.0290085 0.0290067
outer loop
vertex -49.9346 85.733 -1356.86
vertex -49.9346 86.6265 -1357.76
vertex -49.9633 86.6745 -1356.82
endloop
endfacet
facet normal 0.996327 0.0262471 0.0815064
outer loop
vertex -49.9346 85.733 -1356.86
vertex -49.9633 86.6745 -1356.82
vertex -50.0151 85.733 -1355.88
endloop
endfacet
endsolid WEMtoSTL_0
```

The `facet` and `endfacet` tags can be repeated as much as needed.

This is what I tried:

```
Scanner face_scanner = new Scanner(file);
face_scanner.useDelimiter("solid | facet normal | outer loop | vertex | endloop | endfacet");
```

But `face_scanner.next()` doesn't result in the following that I want to get:

```
0.999309 0.0262812 0.0262796
-49.9111 85.733 -1357.76
-49.9346 86.6265 -1357.76
-49.9346 85.733 -1356.86
and so on...
```

Edit:
I tried now the following:

```
Scanner face_scanner = new Scanner(file);
face_scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
face_scanner.useDelimiter("\\s|\n");

while (face_scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (face_scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
        float curr = face_scanner.nextFloat();
    } else {
        String s = face_scanner.next();
    }
}
```

For my example file with 22402 lines this takes more than 2 minutes. Is it possible to do it in a few seconds or even less? 2 minutes is far too much for me.

Comment: Hint : you could use the `split` funciton of the String class instead..

Comment: Is the performance of `split` better than `Scanner`? Because I need good performance due to big files up to 15MB.

Comment: Right now you are using a Scanner to parse the file as if you hardly know what it looks like. "Is it a float? then read a float". But you have a very specific data format. For example if a line starts with 'vertex' then you KNOW it will be followed by three floating point numbers. Use that knowledge to create a far more deterministic parser; I would just use BufferedReader to loop through the file line by line myself and that has always worked fine for me, including parsing files into the gigabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Antlr would be a good alternative; It has good performance/memory characteristics, and all of the low level tokenization is handled by for you.

There's a grammar [here](https://github.com/ununbium/stl-serialization-tools/blob/master/stl-parse/src/main/antlr4/StlAscii.g4) (Disclaimer: I am the author) for the STL ASCII format.

It's part of a larger project that has a Java STL model, see [here](https://github.com/ununbium/stl-serialization-tools) (Disclaimer: I am the author of this too). A quick test shows a 5.5 second parse time for a ~19MB STL file.